# Setting permissions at the route level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails and I am using devise for authentication.

I have a route called `/users/5/events/1/add_images` to which the current_user should only have access if `@user == current_user`. What's the best way to set this permission? Should this be done on the controller level?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be done at the controller level.

You can use the `cancan` gem for handling authorization.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Roughly, you have to define the ability:

```
can :add_images, Event do |event|
    event.user.id == user.id
end
```

In the events_controller, add a before_filter

```
before_filter :find_event # set @event
before_filter :authorize_add_images, only: :add_images

def authorize_add_images
    authorize! :add_images, @event
end
```

That's the general idea, read the doc for the rest.

Comment: Especially as @user and current_user) don't exist at the routing level

Comment: yea, i realized that the user passed in is already the current_user